# How to disable annoying multiple cursor shapes placement in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, position, mouse-cursor

Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1 - the latest one.

Everything was OK and either I hit a wrong short key combination and turned that on or it is a bug.

I have no idea what is that and definitely it's not useful for me, rather makes coding impossible when I need to select something since it just places the cursor everywhere.

What is this and how disable it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You might consider providing a greater explanation than just the screenshot, as well as providing relevant details, such as the version of Android Studio that you are using.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am sorry, bro. I edited the question, added more details. Thanks.

Comment: I get a vaguely similar effect from Edit > Add Carets to Ends of Selected Lines, but the effect is not durable -- if I click elsewhere, things return to normal. I also get a vaguely similar effect from Edit > Column Selection Mode, but not with the staggered behavior. But, check to see if those have an impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled `Column Selection Mode`. You can disable it under `Edit -> Column Selection Mode`